# Mysql query group by to be combined with order by desc

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by

I have the following query as below.

```
SELECT Day(vehicleTrip.startDateTime) As day, 
       Month(vehicleTrip.startDateTime) As month,
       Sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDateTime, endDateTime )) As totalDuration,
       count(vehicleTrip.startDateTime) As totalTrip, 
       sum(endMileage-startMileage) As totalMleage
FROM vehicleTrip                            
WHERE vehicleTrip.vehicleID=:vehicleID
  AND vehicleTrip.vehicleEndCodeID!=1
  AND vehicleTrip.startDateTime BETWEEN :startDateTime And :endDateTime                             
Group By Day(vehicleTrip.startDateTime),Month(vehicleTrip.startDateTime)
```

Currently it works fine cause it can group by the daily date the sum of `duration, totalTrip, totalMileage etc.` But only issue I want the date to be arrange by desc. I have tried putting the order by startDateTime desc it gives `me error that its not in GROUP By clause and containts nonaggregated column`. I have tried many method like even putting the `Max(vehicleTrip.startDateTime)` still the same. How best can I resolve this ?

Below is my table design with its index.

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicleTrip` (
  `vehicleEndCodeID` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `vehicleID` mediumint NOT NULL,
  `startDateTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `endDateTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `startMileage` float(11,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endMileage` float(11,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startLatitude` float(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `startLongitude` float(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `endLatitude` float(10,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endLongitude` float(11,8) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `vehicleTrip`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`vehicleID`,`startDateTime`) USING BTREE;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
SELECT Day(startDateTime) As "day", 
       Month(startDateTime) As "month",
       Sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, startDateTime, endDateTime ))
             As totalDuration,
       count(*) As trips, 
       sum(endMileage-startMileage) As totalMleage
FROM vehicleTrip                            
WHERE vehicleID = :vehicleID
  AND vehicleEndCodeID != 1
  AND startDateTime BETWEEN :startDateTime And :endDateTime                             
Group By 2, 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 DESC
```

(I'm assuming you want to sort by both month and day, latest first?)

Also consider

```
GROUP BY DATE(startDateTime)
ORDER BY DATE(startDateTime) DESC
```

**More**

`!=` is hard to optimize.  I don't see any way to avoid the 'filesort', but this index *might* help with performance:

```
INDEX(vehicleID, startDateTime)   -- in this order
```

However, since that is already the `PRIMARY KEY`, do not add this `INDEX`.

**Starting over**

Now that the `CREATE TABLE` has been added (and this is why I ask for such so often), here is how I would answer the question:

When possible, have the *same* `ORDER BY` as `GROUP BY`.  This allows the Optimizer to both at the same time.  In your question, you did not quite have the same stuff in each.

A variation on such is to change the direction:

```
GROUP BY a     , b
ORDER BY a DESC, b DESC
```

is also optimal.

(Not relevant here:)  In most cases, any mixture of ASC and DESC on the columns in `ORDER BY` prevents any optimization of the `ORDER BY`.

My suggestion of using `DATE(..)` instead of the two columns avoids the issue and solves the potential bug that will show up next January.  BUT...  It may run into the "only full group by" issues since `DAY(..), MONTH(..)` is not recognized as a subset of `DATE(..)

To avoid some of the above mess, I started by suggesting

```
GROUP BY 2     , 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 DESC
```

If this fails, I will pull a subquery out of my sleeve.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112580/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-mysql-query-group-by-to-be-combined-with-orde).